# Node.js: Awaiting a Require

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, azure-keyvault

I'm new the `Node.js` and I've been working with a sample project by a third party provider and I'm trying to use Azure Key Vault to store configuration values.

I'm having trouble getting a process to `wait` before executing the rest. I'll try to detail as much as I know.

The [sample project](https://github.com/LivePersonInc/messaging_bot_samples) has a file named `agent.js` which is the start page/file. On [line 16](https://github.com/LivePersonInc/messaging_bot_samples/blob/172707fc1d062cbb1e67055db305eb1a6adb7551/agent.js#L16) (`agent_config = require('./config/config.js')[process.env.LP_ACCOUNT][process.env.LP_USER]`) it calls a config file with values. I'm trying to set these value using Key Vault. I've tried many combinations of calling functions, and even implementing `async / await` but the value for `agent_config` always contains a `[Promise]` object and not the data returned by Key Vault.

If I'm right, this is because the Key Vault itself uses `async / await` too and the config file returns before the Key Vault values are returned.

How can Key Vault be added/implemented in a situation like this?

Here's what I've tried:

First updated **agent.js** to

```
let agent_config = {};
try {
  agent_config = require('./config/config.js')['123']['accountName'];
} catch (ex) {
  log.warn(`[agent.js] Error loading config: ${ex}`)
}

console.log(agent_config);
```

### Test 1

**./config/config.js**

```
const KeyVault = require('azure-keyvault');
const msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
const KEY_VAULT_URI = 'https://' + '{my vault}' + '.vault.azure.net/' || process.env['KEY_VAULT_URI'];

function getValue(secretName, secretVersion) {
  msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({ resource: 'https://vault.azure.net' }).then((credentials) => {
    const client = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);
    client.getSecret(KEY_VAULT_URI, secretName, secretVersion).then(
      function (response) {
        return response.Value;
      });
  });
}

module.exports = {
    '123': {
        'accountName': {
            accountId: getValue('mySecretName', '')
         }
     }
};
```

**Results**

> { accountsId: undefined }

### Test 2

Made **getValue** an `async` function and wrapped it around another function (tried without the wrapping and didn't work either)

**./config/config.js**

```
const KeyVault = require('azure-keyvault');
const msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
const KEY_VAULT_URI = 'https://' + '{my vault}' + '.vault.azure.net/' || process.env['KEY_VAULT_URI'];

async function getValue(secretName, secretVersion) {
  msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({ resource: 'https://vault.azure.net' }).then((credentials) => {
    const client = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);
    client.getSecret(KEY_VAULT_URI, secretName, secretVersion).then(
      function (response) {
        return response.Value;
      });
  });
}

async function config() {
    module.exports = {
        '123': {
            'accountName': {
                accountId: await getValue('mySecretName', '')
             }
         }
    };
}

config();
```

**Results**

> {}

### Test 3

Made **getValue** an `async` function and wrapped it around another function (tried without the wrapping and didn't work either)

**./config/config.js**

```
const KeyVault = require('azure-keyvault');
const msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
const KEY_VAULT_URI = 'https://' + '{my vault}' + '.vault.azure.net/' || process.env['KEY_VAULT_URI'];

async function getValue(secretName, secretVersion) {
  return msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({ resource: 'https://vault.azure.net' })
    .then((credentials) => {
      const client = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);
      return client.getSecret(KEY_VAULT_URI, secretName, secretVersion).then(
        function (response) {
          return response.Value;
        });
    });
}

module.exports = {
    '123': {
        'accountName': {
            accountId: getValue('mySecretName', '')
        }
    }
};

config();
```

**Results**

> { accountId: { <pending> } }

### Other

I've tried many others ways like `module.exports = async (value) =< {...}` (found through other questions/solutions without success.

I'm starting to think I need to do some "waiting" on `agent.js` but I haven't found good info on this.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue is that your `getValue` function is not returning anything as your returns need to be explicit.

(and without the promise being returned, there's nothing to await on)

```
async function getValue(secretName, secretVersion) {
  return msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({ resource: 'https://vault.azure.net' })
    .then((credentials) => {
      const client = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);
      return client.getSecret(KEY_VAULT_URI, secretName, secretVersion).then(
        function (response) {
          return response.Value;
        });
    });
}
```

You could also get away with less explicit returns using arrow functions..

```
const getValue = async (secretName, secretVersion) => 
  msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({ resource: 'https://vault.azure.net' })
    .then(credentials => {
      const client = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);
      return client.getSecret(KEY_VAULT_URI, secretName, secretVersion)
        .then(response => response.Value);
    });
```

Introducing the Azure Key Vault read, which is async, means your whole config read is async. There' nothing you can do to get around that. This will mean that the code that uses the config will need to handle it appropriately. You start by exporting an async function that will return the config..

```
async function getConfig() {
  return {
    '123': {
      'accountName': {
        accountId: await getValue('mySecretName', '')
      }
    }
  };
}

module.exports = getConfig;
```

In your agent code you call that function. This will mean that your agent code will need to be wrapped in a function too, so maybe something like this..

```
const Bot = require('./bot/bot.js');
const getConfig = require('./config/config.js');

getConfig().then(agentConfig => {
    const agent = new Bot(agentConfig);

    agent.on(Bot.const.CONNECTED, data => {
        log.info(`[agent.js] CONNECTED ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. However this results in the same thing. `{ accountId: Promise { <pending> } }`

Comment: added this as Test 3

Comment: You are not doing it right in the test 3. You should await on `getValue`. But this will introduce that your config should be wrapped inside an async function, something like test 1. Btw, you're doing it wrong in test 1: don't set `module.exports` there, instead return an object that will be assigned to `module.exports`.

Comment: added a usage example to my answer

Comment: @lecstor thank you for your sample usage. When I use it as-is I get the following error `"Unexpected identifier"`.  It seems to be at `function async getConfig() {...}` When I switch the order of `function` and `async` I don't get an error, however I do get a result of `{ accountId: undefined }`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RoLYroLLs could it be that you don't have the secret with that name in your Azure vault?

Comment: @RoLYroLLs can you check if this would work? https://gist.github.com/Pritilender/7ae1d68331b5f76c818e601760bd2db2

Comment: oops, thanks, fixed typo. Not sure about the undefined accountId now. I'd add logging to getValue to check `credentials` and `response` are what is expected.

Comment: @lecstor The script by Pritilender actually works. Not sure why.

Comment: `response => response.Value` looks like "value" needs to be lowercase

Comment: @lecstor your script DOES work too!! I found another typo that threw me off. Your `getValue` function has an extra `}` at the end. I thought you forgot an opening one at the beginning. Instead I removed the last `}` and it worked. I can't edit your post due to only changing 1 character

Comment: @RoLYroLLs my script is just async/await rewrite of lecstor's
Even though you managed to make his code work, I'd advise against this coding style since it makes the code a bit unreadable. No hard feelings lecstor, just if you're already stating that the function is async, then use await in it, instead of nesting promise callbacks.

Comment: @Pritilender, all good, I'd agree with that, I was just trying to keep the code as close to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The package `azure-keyvault` has been deprecated in favor of the new packages to deal with Keyvault keys, secrets and certificates separately. For your scenario, you can use the new [@azure/keyvault-secrets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/keyvault-secrets) package to talk to Key Vault and the new [@azure/identity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/identity) package to create the credential.

```js
const { SecretClient } = require("@azure/keyvault-secrets");
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");

async function getValue(secretName, secretVersion) {
  const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
  const client = new SecretClient(KEY_VAULT_URI, credential);
  const secret = await client.getSecret(secretName);
  return secret.value;
}
```

The `DefaultAzureCredential` assumes that you have set the below env variables

- AZURE_TENANT_ID: The tenant ID in Azure Active Directory
- AZURE_CLIENT_ID: The application (client) ID registered in the AAD tenant
- AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET: The client secret for the registered application

To try other credentials, see the [readme for @azure/identity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/identity)
If you are moving from the older azure-keyvault package, checkout the [migration guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/keyvault-secrets/migration-guide.md) to understand the major changes